# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: yoga (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR):

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to create an app. App is opening in Emulator. But when I am trying to open the app in real device, it is crashing. I tried many solutions regarding my problem. but I am unable to solve my problem. I added DatabaseHelper, Logcat. I added android.permission in AndroidManifest.xml but failed to get solution. App is not opening. Application terminated. not opening. Please suggest to solve this problem.

I deleted the app before running the app in real device. But problem remains same.

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static DatabaseHelper mInstance = null;


    String DB_PATH = null;
    private static String DB_NAME = "kriyayoga.db";
    private static SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private  final Context myContext;
    private  static  final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {

        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
        this.DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + "databases/";
        //this.DB_PATH = this.myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getAbsolutePath();
        Log.e("Path 1", DB_PATH);

    }


    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (dbExist) {
        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        File dbFile = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion)
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

**Logcat** Problem shows at ListNavAdapter.java

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: yoga
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: yoga (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: SELECT heading FROM yoga ORDER BY _id
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:946)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:527)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1408)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1347)
        at com.priyanka.kriyayoga.ListNavAdapter.onViewCreated(ListNavAdapter.java:81)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1471)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:802)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2625)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2411)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2366)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1395)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7293)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3196)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2011)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7135)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:876)
```

When I am running the app in real device it says **runtime exception**

App is experiencing crashes.

in **AndroidManifest.xml** I added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

In **ListNavAdapter** I used to get data

```
SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this.getContext()).getReadableDatabase();
 Cursor cursor1 = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT heading FROM yoga ORDER BY _id", new String[]{});
```

Comment: where do you create your tables? Shouldn't it be on the onCreate method of the DatabaseHelper?

Comment: @joao86 I have added db file within asset. In emulator everything fine but when opening real device, app terminated and crashes.

Comment: first remove that column then compile and check the result

Comment: @kam1234 which column will i remove?

Comment: @priyankanaskar probably because in the device the database is not saved in the same location as in the emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is very likely that the device on which you are trying this is Android 9+. With 9+ the default was changed from journal mode to WAL (Write Ahead Logging).

Using **getWritableDatabase** (or **getReadableDatabase**, *they both open the database as writable if the database can be opened as writable*) before the copy results in the **-wal** and **-shm** files being created. When the database is copied the -wal and -shm files remain. When the copied database is opened, the **-wal** file is opened by SQLite and a discrepancy is found as the **-wal** file belongs to the overwritten database file NOT the copied database file. In order to provide a usable database, the corrupt database file is then overwritten with a valid and therefore empty database file and hence why the table(s) appear to have vanished.

Historically (I believe as I can see no other reason) **getWritableDatabase** was used to get-around a cannot open file ENONENT error, this because when a App is first run, the **databases** directory does not exists in the data/data/package_name directory (so the copy of the file fails).

The following changes will circumvent this issue by making the **databases** directory (which is more efficient) when needed.

First change :-

```
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    File dbFile = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
    return dbFile.exists();
}
```

to be :-

```
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    File dbFile = myContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME);
    if (dbFile.exists()) return true;
    if (!dbFile.getParentFile().exists()) {
        dbfile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then remove or comment out the line **`this.getReadableDatabase()`**, in the **createDataBase** method.

**Note** the above code is **in-principle code**, it has not been run or tested and may therefore contain errors.